# Islamic Week number

Tags: sql, sql-server, week-number

We are a company based in England and we also have another branch out in Dubai.
I must be missing something simple but how do I get the Islamic Week number from SQL server (2008 R2) - the server is based in England so we can't change much.

I've created the following test query to demonstrate the issue, (the column called "WhatWeWant" where i subtract -1 from the week number is to demonstrate the required answers within this example and NOT a fix)

```
DATEFIRST only affects the ww column and not the ISO_WEEK column.

SELECT
        [xdate]
      , DATEPART(ww, xdate) as ww      
      , DATEPART(ISO_Week, xdate) as iso_week
      , DATEPART(ww, xdate) -1 as whatWeWant
  FROM [test].[dbo].[testing]
```

results:

```
xdate                        ww iso_week whatWeWant
2016-11-18 00:00:00.0000000  47 46       46
2016-11-19 00:00:00.0000000  47 46       46
2016-11-20 00:00:00.0000000  48 46       47
2016-11-21 00:00:00.0000000  48 47       47
2016-11-22 00:00:00.0000000  48 47       47
2016-11-23 00:00:00.0000000  48 47       47
2016-11-24 00:00:00.0000000  48 47       47
2016-11-25 00:00:00.0000000  48 47       47
2016-11-26 00:00:00.0000000  48 47       47
2016-11-27 00:00:00.0000000  49 47       48
2016-11-28 00:00:00.0000000  49 48       48
2016-11-29 00:00:00.0000000  49 48       48
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I'm confused.  Is the ISO week the same as the Islamic week?

Comment: @GordonLinoff `2016-11-27 00:00:00.0000000  49 47       48` in example it is not as you can see in the line.

Comment: It seems ISO_WEEK produces the same result as `DATEPART(ww, xdate) -1` you use SET DATEFIRST 1. However, Simon says the desired result for 20 Nov 2016 is 47 (and if you use SET DATEFIRST 1 it only changes the WhatWeWant column to something else than what he really wants).

Comment: The iso_week is nearly what I want, except it starts on Monday, and the Islamic week starts Sunday, so it's on the 20th that the problem can be seen in the example. there must be a simple way to do this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    [xdate]
  , DATEPART(ww, xdate) as ww      
  , DATEPART(ISO_Week, xdate) as iso_week
  , DATEPART(ww, xdate) -1 as whatWeWant
  , DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, DATEADD(DAY,1,xdate)) as whatIPropose
FROM [test].[dbo].[testing]
```

It seems to produce the expected result, regardless of the DATEFIRST setting.

Comment: Thank you, a simple neat solution

Comment: @Simon Will that really work in all years? For example, in 2015, the date 1 January was a Thursday. So with the ISO week, with the week starting on a Monday and ending on a Sunday, the week __from Mon. 29 Dec. 2014 through Sun. 4 Jan. 2015__ belongs to 2015 and is Week 1 of 2015. But with the Arab convention, the "same" week goes __from Sun. 28 Dec. 2014 through Sat. 3 Jan 2015__. Would they really call that Week 1 (of 2015) in Dubai? It would be more natural to have it belong to 2014, or to have distinct week numbers for the two "portions" of the week.

Comment: In 2026, the year will start on a Thursday again.